# error from tree top detection in ForestTools R package

Tags: r, linear-regression, r-raster, lidar

My goal is to detect tree tops using ForestTools::vwf() algorithm. I understand we need to determine a variable moving window size based on a linear regression between tree height and crown width (following this example: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ForestTools/vignettes/treetopAnalysis.html)

Here is my code:

```
#
chm <- raster("chm.tif") ## Canopy Height Model raster of 0.25 m resolution
#
# read tree measurements (tm) dataframe
tm <- structure(list(Id = 1:22, tree_height = c(26.52, 30.18, 17.98, 25.91, 
24.08, 10.36, 15.24, 25.6, 22.86, 26.21, 22.56, 22.25, 24.08, 17.37, 20.42, 
27.13, 20.73, 10.36, 4.88, 4.88, 9.45, 7.015), crown_width = c(177.38, 169.69, 
274.51, 293.41, 163.11, 97.88, 52.20, 490.73, 81.29, 189.05, 59.36, 210.83, 
393.13, 201.74, 216.47, 296.87, 108.06, 47.56, 18.75, 19.15, 47.58, 25.36)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))
#
head(tm) ##this is how my df is organized
#  Id tree_height crown_width
#1  1     26.5176    177.3790
#2  2     30.1752    169.6940
#3  3     17.9832    274.5130
#4  4     25.9080    293.4080
#5  5     24.0792    163.1080
#6  6     10.3632     97.8815
#
lin <- lm(crown_width ~ tree_height, data = tm) 
print(lin)
#Coefficients:
#      (Intercept)  tree_height
#           3.0158       0.5483
linearModel <- function(x){x * 0.5483 + 3.0158}
ttops <- ForestTools::vwf(CHM = chm, winFun = linearModel, minHeight = 2)
```

However, I get the following **error** from the tree top detection algorithm ForestTools::vwf():

Error in ForestTools::vwf(CHM = chm, winFun = linearModel, minHeight = 2) :
Input function for 'winFun' yields a window diameter of 163 cells, which is wider than the maximum allowable value in 'maxWinDiameter'.
Change the 'winFun' function or set 'maxWinDiameter' to a higher value (or to NULL).

**My understanding of this error is that my variable moving window size is larger than the maximum diameter set in the algorithm -- Does anyone know how to fix this?**

Comment: [Looks like](https://rdrr.io/cran/ForestTools/man/vwf.html) the default for `maxWinDiameter` is 99. Maybe try adding `maxWinDiameter = 200` to your `vwf` call?

Comment: @nniloc thanks! I tried doing that (or changing it to NULL) -- it works but the moving window size is too large and end up missing several trees. I'm wondering if it's something related to my regression model?

Comment: Maybe there is something off with your data `tm`. Units are off (feet vs meters)? Or the labels are switched? I would expect tree height to be larger than crown width. Just a guess.